# Чи головоломка є українським словом?

Tags: вибір-слова, росіянізм

В [російсько-українських словниках початку ХХ століття](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) як відповідники слова *головоломка* надано *морока, заморока*. В Російсько-українському народному словнику 2009– пропонується ще *за́моро́чка, головокрутка, крутиголовка*, але не *головоломка*. 
[СЛОВНИК УКРАЇНСЬКОЇ МОВИ ONLINE.ТОМИ 1-8.](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=19147&page=653) містить лише одне слово зі значенням "*Складна загадка або задача, для розв'язання якої потрібна кмітливість.*"- *головоломка*.

Чи назва іграшки *головоломка* є росіянізмом і краще віддати перевагу певному із пропонованих іншими словниками українському слову, чи воно відповідає особливостям українського словотвору і має право на вживання?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слово "головоломка" можна знайти в [СУМі](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=19147&page=653), де у нього таке ж саме значення яке ви навели. А от в [етимологічному словнику](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/cgi-bin/ua/elib.exe?Z21ID=&I21DBN=UKRLIB&P21DBN=UKRLIB&S21STN=1&S21REF=10&S21FMT=online_book&C21COM=S&S21CNR=20&S21P01=0&S21P02=0&S21P03=FF=&S21STR=ukr0001070) даного слова немає, однак там є слово "головолом", яке було утворене від "іменника голова та дієслова ломити", тому теоретично слово "головоломка" могло також бути утворене від цих слів.
Крім того в англійській мові цьому слову відповідає слово "puzzle" і при його перекладі ми отримаємо також варіант ["головоломка"](https://translate.google.com/?hl=uk#en/uk/puzzle) (теж саме буде якщо перекласти з російської "головоломка" на українську). А якщо зазирнути у [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/pazly), то такий варіант ми знайдемо серед українських відповідників до слова "пазли", а також там є непогані варіанти "заморока" та "складанка" (однак з останнім варто [бути уважнішим](http://redactor.in.ua/ru/language/6763.Kult_movi_Yak_pereklasti_self%D1%96), адже воно має вужче значення в українській мові).

Також шукаючи інформацію я теж зустрів питання: "Чи є слово "головоломка" русизмом?" Однак ніякого підтвердження тому, що це русизм я не знайшов, адже цього слова немає ні у списку анти-суржиків на [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%97:%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA), ні в інших схожих списках на сайтах присвячених українській мові.